# Ember App Kit (EAK) storge all component relevant information within one folder

Tags: ember.js, ember-app-kit

i want to create a ember component and store all relevant component parts (e.g. templates, scripts) in the same folder. Current the Ember App Kit requires to store all components js files within the appkit/components folder and the templates files (.hba) within appkit/templates/components folder.

Thats because of the naming convention and the appkit resolver.

Is there any way to overide this behavior.

My component folder structure goal is.

Foo Folder

- index.hbs
- index.js
- script2.js

Currently folder structure

/components/index.js
/templates/components/index.hbs